# TailwindCSS 3 + Symfony / webpack Encore Not Styling?

Tags: symfony, webpack, tailwind-css, postcss, webpack-encore

I updated to TailwindCSS 3 in a symfony 6 app. When I compile the stylesheets there are no errors (it compiles successfully) but none of the tailwind class styles work. I notice the imports for tailwind don't seem to be translating from the @tailwindcss calls (they are just included as-is in the browser). Maybe a postCSS issue?

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const path = require('path');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    .copyFiles([
        {
            from: './assets/images',
            to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]',
        }
    ])

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */

    .addEntry('main', './assets/main.js')

    .addEntry('admin', './assets/admin.js')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .configureBabel((config) => {
        config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    // Enable PostCSS loader
    .enablePostCssLoader((options) => {
        options.postcssOptions = {
            // the directory where the postcss.config.js file is stored
            config: './postcss.config.js',
        };
    })

    .splitEntryChunks()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

`postcss.config.js`:

```js
let tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'),
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('autoprefixer')
    ]
}
```

`tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    darkMode: 'media'
}
```

`main.css` (imported via `main.js`):

```css
@import '~tailwindcss/base';
@import '~tailwindcss/components';
@import '~tailwindcss/utilities';

/* Rest of custom content... */
```

I added `console.log()`s to the various config files and they all show as being loaded/accessed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had a similar problem. I think in the new tailwind you should always add the locations of your templates and do something like:

---

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./assets/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        "./templates/**/*.{html,twig}",
    ],
    theme: {
      extend: {
          fontFamily: {
              sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
          },
      }
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was going to try that next. I'm guessing it is needed with 3's enabling of JIT.